# PIN screen not displayed when app comes back to foreground

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm building an app in Jetpack Compose where users can set a personalized PIN that will be stored in sharedPrefs. Every time the app comes back to the foreground (and users have setup a PIN beforehand), the app should open the "enter PIN" screen. On app start, everything works fine and users are prompted to enter their PIN, but once the app goes into the background and then back into the foreground, the "enter PIN" screen is not shown anymore.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val openPinScreen = MutableStateFlow(false)

    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPrefsRepository: SharedPrefsRepository

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val pinState = openPinScreen.collectAsState()

            MyAppTheme {
                MyApp(pinState.value)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        sharedPrefsRepository.getPin()?.let {
            openPinScreen.value = sharedPrefsRepository.hasSetPin()
        }
    }
}

fun MyApp(showPin: Boolean) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Route.Splash.route) {
        composable(Route.Splash.route) {
            SplashScreen {
                navController.apply {
                    popBackStack()
                    navigate(Route.MainContent.route)
                }
            }
        }
        composable(Route.MainContent.route) {
            MainContent(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.White),
                isPinRequired = showPin
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**MainContent.kt**

```
fun MainContent(
    modifier: Modifier,
    isPinRequired: Boolean,
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

    val shouldOpenPinScreen by remember {
        mutableStateOf(isPinRequired)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(isPinRequired){
        if (shouldOpenPinScreen) navController.navigate(Route.Pincode.route)
    }

    Scaffold(...){ 
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Route.Home.route
        ) {
            composable(...) {...}
            composable(...) {...}
            composable(...) {...}
    }
}
```

I've checked during debugging that everything works fine in MainActivity but there seems to be a problem when trying to get the value to the respective Composable. Specifically,

```
LaunchedEffect(isPinRequired){
   if (shouldOpenPinScreen) navController.navigate(Route.Pincode.route)
}
```

is not called anymore and navigation to `Route.Pincode.route` is not triggered. Replacing `LaunchedEffect(isPinRequired)` with `LaunchedEffect(Unit)` also didn't help. Anyone got any ideas on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lays in these lines:

```
val shouldOpenPinScreen by remember {
    mutableStateOf(isPinRequired)
}
```

`shouldOpenPinScreen` fixes the first value of `isPinRequired` and is not updated with the new value. You can pass `isPinRequired` as a key to `remember`, in which case the variable will be updated. But I generally don't see the point in having this variable, if it's always the same as `isPinRequired`, you can probably remove it and replace it by just using `isPinRequired`.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed `shouldOpenPinScreen`. Unfortunately, the PIN screen is still not displayed. I've noticed during debugging that `val pinState = openPinScreen.collectAsState()` is only executed on app start. Do you know how I can change this line so that it's triggered every single time?

Comment: @masterR0shi `collectAsState` will trigger recompose every time `openPinScreen` value changes. Try adding print to `onResume` to make sure that `openPinScreen.value` is `false` before you set it and `true` after.